# Looking for explanation to solution - divergence theorem, differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, volume, divergence-operator

What is the volume of the domain to which the cube $|x| < 1, |y| < 1, |z| < 1$ move to after 20 time units, when its motion is governed by the system

$\begin{cases}\dot x = \cos(x+y+z) \\ \dot y = -\sin(y+z) \\ \dot z = -\cos(x+y+z)+\sin(y+z)+2z\end{cases}$

**Solution**
Let $\Omega(t)$ be the domain at time $t$. At $t=0$ this is the cube we were given, and the volume is $V(0) = \int_{\Omega(0)}dxdydz = 2^3 = 8$

Notice that the divergence of this system (the right side of the system) is $2$, and so:

$\dot V = \int_{\Omega(t)}\text{div}(F)dxdydz = 2\int_{\Omega(t)}dxdydz = 2V$

Hence $V(t) = V(0)e^{2t} = 8e^{2t}$ so our answer is $V(20) = 8e^{40}$

**My issue is**

I'm not sure why $\dot V = \int_{\Omega(t)}\text{div}(F)dxdydz$. I understood everything else.

Comment: If you want a rigorous proof for this, take a look at Meiss' _Differential dynamical systems_ (9.2, Volume preserving flows) or Strogatz's _Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos ..._ (9.2, Simple properties of Lorenz Equations, Volume Contraction).